# Casting const pointer to non const

Tags: c++

```
extern const map<string, vector<unsigned char>> my_map;

// get const reference, no copying
const vector<unsigned char> &data = my_map.at("my_key");

// also no copy?
istringstream iss;
iss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf((char *)data.data(), data.size());
```

How does the last line work? I saw it on multiple SO answers on how to create a `istringstream` without copying.

If I understand this correctly, `data` is a const reference to the element of the map whose key is *"my_key"*. And since `at()` returns by const reference as well, the values of the vector weren't copied. But since it's a const reference, then I can't change the elements of the vector.

`data()` returns a `const unsigned char*`, which I cast to `char*`. Does this mean that the elements of the array can now be changed? (since its a pointer to a non-const type). Or did the vector get copied when I casted it?

Comment: Is (or will lead to) Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @RichardCritten only if you write into those `char`s, which `std::istringstream` isn't likely to do

Comment: Be *very* careful when casting away `const`. Prefer never to do it. If the object you cast `const` away from was initially declared as `const` your code has Undefined Behaviour if you ever modify the object. Casting away `const` is *only* valid if the object in question was originally declared non-const - and that can be extremely difficult to know for sure (and even when you do known it is still a highly suspicious thing to do).

Comment: Note that `basic_stringbuf::setbuf` has implementation-defined behaviour. `pubsetbuf` may well do nothing at all.

Comment: "*Does this mean that the elements of the array can now be changed?*" - not safely, no. The contents of the `map` are const and presumably read-only, casting away constness doesn't change that. Also, the correct C++-style cast would be `const_cast<char *>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data())` instead of the C style cast `(char*)data.data()`. "*Or did the vector get copied when I casted it?*" - no, it was not copied.

Comment: @Caleth you are absolutely correct and I can see nothing in the docs that even suggests  `std::istringstream` can modify the contents of the buffer.

Comment: @Caleth what exactly does *implementation-defined* mean? What's an "implementation"?

Comment: We had a similar question recently. I'm not convinced there's any UB here. It's possible I said the opposite at the time.

Comment: @Tirafesi The "implementation" is your compiler + its friends/associated tools (including standard library). It means "implementation of the C++ standard". Regarding _implementation-defined behaviour_: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/560648

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean that the elements of the array can now be changed?

It means that the type of the pointer is such that it is well-formed to modify the object through the pointer. This means that the compiler is not required to give you a diagnostic message and assuming the entire program is well-formed, the compiler is required to not fail compilation (some restrictions apply).

However, if the pointed object is a const object then the behaviour of modifying it through the pointer to non-const would be undefind.

But the vector elements in this case are non-const (because the template type argument is non-const), so modifying them would be defined. It might be surprising to the reader of the program though. Another matter is whether `std::istringstream` ever modifies the pointed objects or not.

Comment: But _is_ the vector "a const object"? That's not clear to me.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Hmm good point. Or rather, is the buffer of the vector const. It's a vector of non-const, so... I guess not.

Comment: Funnily enough, yes that also. I'm not convinced the vector is const, and even if it is I'm not convinced that its buffer is const! And if both of those things are not const then `const_cast`ing to your heart's content is, while unwise, not illegal or undefined.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Amended the answer.

Comment: To be clear, this is speculation on my part. It's not clear to me; I'm not making a claim! There was a debate about this recently and it was never settled.